# Standalone Hornetq Cluster set up on Remote Machines

Tags: hornetq

Can any body tell me how to create standalone Hornetq cluster setup on Remote machines?

thanks in advance..

Comment: we have written a manual to that. You're basically asking me to repeat myself on the manual with a broad question. 

I suggest you read the doc, or if you don't want that.. at least look at the examples on the distribution.

Comment: thanks for your response. i followed the manual to do that. i have set up two server on two remote machines, they are able to start but they are unable to recognize each other. manual is like patches, no help from google also.. if possible can you just give the example configuration files for cluster... that would be great help to me... i spent a day to set this up...

Comment: There are many examples... you should ask something more specific